# Subtracting perl while in loop with other contraints

Tags: perl

I want to get the value from an array thats in a while fetchrow.. if that makes sense.
heres my code and the output to help explain

```
while (@data = $STH2->fetchrow_array()) {

                           print "<tr>";
                           print "<td>$_</td>" for @data[0,1];

                           print "</tr>";
```

and this outputs

```
$data[0]   |  $data[1]
   1       |    1000
   1       |    400
   12      |    500
   12      |    150
```

(each `$data[0]` will only output 2 values)

what i want to do is subtract the 2 `$data[1]` values from each other (ie. 1000-400) for each different `$data[0]` value then print that. I cant figure out how to do this, thank you for any help.

Comment: Yikes, raw output.  Please consider `use HTML::Entities qw(encode_entities)` and then something like `print "<td>$_</td> for map {encode_entities($_)} @data[0,1];`

Comment: @pilcrow: sometimes you can rely on numbers not needing encoding :)

Comment: @ysth: sometimes external data sources become tomorrow's injection vector.  Seatbelts, `strict`, and output encoding — make them your defaults. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just capture the values in a hash of array references and then do the subtraction later (**Warning:** Untested):

```
my %data_hash=(); #keys: $data[0], values: array ref of $data[1] corresponding to $data[0]

while(@data=$STH2->fetchrow_array)
{
  push @{$data_hash{$data[0]}},$data[1];
}

foreach(sort{$a<=>$b}(keys %data_hash))
{
  print "<tr>";
  print "<td>$_</td>";
  my $diff=$data_hash{$_}->[0] - $data_hash{$_}->[1];
  print "<td>$diff</td>";
  print "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: this didnt seem to work there is a unmatched right curly bracket on the foreach line i dont know where to put the left one.. hashes are new to me in perl..

Comment: wow that perfect thank you so much for your time. any tips on where i can learn hashes better for perl?

Comment: You're welcome.  The official documentation on the basics of Perl data structures is [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html), but I'd recommend getting your hands on a copy of [Learning Perl](http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Perl-Randal-L-Schwartz/dp/1449303587) (aka "The Llama").

Answer (score 1):

it seems like a hash would serve your purposes. $data[0] is the key and $data[1] is the value.

something like

```
my %data;
while (@data = $STH2->fetchrow_array()) {
  if (undefined $data{$data[0]}) {
    $data[$data[0]} = $data[1];
  } else {
    $data[$data[0] -= $data[1];
}
```